# GeoNetwork queries being rejected by Elasticsearch

Tags: geonetwork, ssl, elasticsearch

The gist-- I install GeoNetwork 4.4.3 snapshot, build from source, with Elasticsearch and Kibana 8.11.3 installed and running. GeoNetwork seems to see the ES index (recognized there are records there), but Search always just gets GN error message "Query returned an error. Check the console for details."

Details:

Build GeoNetwork from source. (separate issue... have to manually copy [https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools.jdbc/gt-jdbc-postgis»](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools.jdbc/gt-jdbc-postgis%C2%BB) 30.0 and
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-gml-geometry-streaming » 30.0 into my maven .m2 because maven couldn't access--some kind of certificate problem with maven repo.) Anyway got 4.4.3 snapshot built from a local fork of core-geonetwork, sync'd with main.
Have installed and gotten Elastic Search 8.11.3 working with Kibana 8.11.3. Had to generate and copy xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey, xpack.reporting.encryptionKey, and xpack.security.encryptionKey into kibana.yml, and set xpack.security.enabled: true and xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true in ElasticSearch.yml. That seemed to get Kibana working with Elastic.

Copy geonetwork.war from target dir in core-geonetwork to tomcat9.0.85 webApps folder. In Chrome clear browsing history. start tomcat, after awhile its running. Stop tomcat, put in the Elasticsearch user and password in GeoNetwork config.properties, change protocol to https (tried http first, didn't work).
In GeoNetwork, when I search or goto 'search page' get message "Query returned an error. Check the console for details."

Run admin/status in GeoNetwork, says 'remote index OK'; 'Records in index/db = 6/23' That's odd, Kibana only sees 6 records.

In the Tomcat console I see this

2024-02-11T20:04:48,818 DEBUG

```
[org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor] - Read "application/json;charset=UTF-8" to ["{"from":0,"size":30,"sort":["_score"],"query":{"function_score":{"boost":"5","functions":[{"filter": (truncated)..."]
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

and in the Elastic console this:

```
[2024-02-11T13:20:03,562][WARN ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport] [EMERALD] http client did not trust this server's certificate, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9200, remoteAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:61335}
```

To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

- Start elasticsearch, start kibana, start tomcat (tomcat loads
  geonetwork from webapps)
- Open https://localhost:9200 in browser, have
  to log in with ES username and password; get expected response from
  elastic search.
- Open localhost:5601 in browser, get regular kibana
  page, can look at indexes
- Open localhost:8080/geonetwork, app opens with message "Query returned an error. Check the console for details."

What am I missing?  How do I get Geonetwork search working?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in spite of what the instructions say, geonetwork 4.4.3 doesn't work with ElasticSearch 8.11.3.  I installed Elastic 7.17.15 and got the search working...